# How to copy an href with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to comment into the first post of an instagram profile.

https://www.instagram.com/bestmarketing.es/ this one for example.

I think that posts are not buttons, so I think that I could copy de href of this

And then I could use

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + "href" + "/")
```

This is the important code.

```
<a href="/p/B_m-mIjl-4f/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
a_tags=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']//a")
hrefs=[a_tag.get_attribute('href') for a_tag in a_tags]

for href in hrefs:
    driver.get(href)
    #...do whatever you need here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following css selector.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/bestmarketing.es/")
allurls=[url.get_attribute('href') for url in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w>a")]

for url in allurls:
    driver.get(url)
```